# Individual User ID with Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am attempting to implement a very basic UserID parameter, so that I can more easily slice the data we are receiving (ie attribute User to device, returning/non-returning, location, source, event)

I am using this at the moment to create unique IDs for each visit:

```
var timedate = new Date();
var timedatemil = timedate.getTime();
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX', { 'userId':  timedatemil});
```

To produce a simple ID for each visit. However I am not receiving any data this way when I switch to the userID view. Why would this be? I am running a simple landing page so have no identifiable system to tie it to currently.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of the userid feature - it's not for segmentation, it's to recognize authenticated users across browsers/devices; you cannot access the user id in the reports or in the segmentation tool, you can just see if it is set or not. What you want is a custom dimension. Plus setting this to a timestamp of course defeats the purpose of a user id (but then I gather that was for testing only).

Comment: That is much clearer, thank you for the explanation. With this custom dimension, would that allow me to produce a database with a structure as explained in the question? ie user, recur/new, device etc?